# Time of collapse of stellar dust cloud

Tags: thermodynamics, gravity, astrophysics, astronomy, stars

A stellar gas cloud collapses onto itself once it reaches Jean's mass, and the time it takes for said cloud to collapse is given by: $t_{coll}=\sqrt{\frac{3\pi}{32G\rho_0}}$, where $\rho_0$ is the initial density of the gas cloud. Nonetheless, if I let the cloud begin to collapse onto itself, its density will have changed, and I will now have a different cloud when it comes to density, so $t_{coll}$ is now different. However, my professor told us the time it takes for a gas cloud to collapse depends exclusively on the initial density of the cloud, so my question is, how do we know what density is the initial one if it changes with respect to time as the cloud collapses? Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can calculate the freefall timescale at any point during the collapse, subject to one important condition (see below), and it does get smaller as the collapse proceeds.

The gravitational freefall timescale (which assumes a pressure-less cloud) is the time to collapse from an initial configuration at density $\rho_0$. If you calculate that freefall timescale after the collapse has started you would use a larger $\rho_0$ and the freefall timescale will of course be shorter.

The derivation of the freefall timescale does however assume that the collapse starts from rest with $v_0 = 0$, but since the collapse accelerates continuously then a small initial inward velocity will not change the timescale much as long as the cloud radius is $\gg v_0 t_{\rm coll}$.

Note that this is a rough *timescale* it is not the precise time for the cloud to collapse to zero radius. In practice there are other things that will slow the collapse, not least the fact that the cloud is made of gas that has a pressure.

Answer (score 0):

The cloud is at its initial density when its material is (instantaneously) at rest, i.e., has zero velocity.